# Sliding menu in backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I want to implement a sliding menu using Backbone. Can anyone help me get started?

I have the CSS that slides a menu to right. But how do I structure the backbone views so that when someone clicks a button from one view, the menu view (the other view) gets slided to the right?

I have the following code in the sliding menu view template:

```
    <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left" id="cbp-spmenu-s1">
    <h3>Menu</h3>
    <a href="#">Celery seakale</a>
    <a href="#">Dulse daikon</a>
    <a href="#">Zucchini garlic</a>
    <a href="#">Catsear azuki bean</a>
    <a href="#">Dandelion bunya</a>
    <a href="#">Rutabaga</a>
</nav>
```

and the CSS:

```
.cbp-spmenu {
    background: #47a3da;
    position: fixed;
}

.cbp-spmenu h3 {
    color: #afdefa;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    background: #0d77b6;
}

.cbp-spmenu a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.cbp-spmenu a:hover {
    background: #258ecd;
}

.cbp-spmenu a:active {
    background: #afdefa;
    color: #47a3da;
}

/* Orientation-dependent styles for the content of the menu */

.cbp-spmenu-vertical {
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.cbp-spmenu-vertical a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #258ecd;
    padding: 1em;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal h3 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0.8em;
    border-left: 1px solid #258ecd;
}

/* Vertical menu that slides from the left or right */

.cbp-spmenu-left {
    left: -240px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-right {
    right: -240px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-left.cbp-spmenu-open {
    left: 0px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-right.cbp-spmenu-open {
    right: 0px;
}

/* Horizontal menu that slides from the top or bottom */

.cbp-spmenu-top {
    top: -150px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-bottom {
    bottom: -150px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-top.cbp-spmenu-open {
    top: 0px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-bottom.cbp-spmenu-open {
    bottom: 0px;
}

/* Push classes applied to the body */

.cbp-spmenu-push {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}

.cbp-spmenu-push-toright {
    left: 240px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-push-toleft {
    left: -240px;
}

/* Transitions */

.cbp-spmenu,
.cbp-spmenu-push {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

/* Example media queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 55.1875em){

    .cbp-spmenu-horizontal {
        font-size: 75%;
        height: 110px;
    }

    .cbp-spmenu-top {
        top: -110px;
    }

    .cbp-spmenu-bottom {
        bottom: -110px;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-height: 26.375em){

    .cbp-spmenu-vertical {
        font-size: 90%;
        width: 190px;
    }

    .cbp-spmenu-left,
    .cbp-spmenu-push-toleft {
        left: -190px;
    }

    .cbp-spmenu-right {
        right: -190px;
    }

    .cbp-spmenu-push-toright {
        left: 190px;
    }
}
```

Here's the code that opens the menu

```
$('.example').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('test');
    $('#cbp-spmenu-s1').addClass('cbp-spmenu-open');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

I'm trying to convert this code to Backbone so that one view opens the sliding menu view (that slides to the right).

Comment: Please add some code that whatever you tried so far

Comment: *"I'm trying to convert this code to Backbone so that"* - where's your attempt..? And what's the problem you're facing with it..?

Comment: I don't know how to implement a sliding menu view in backbone so that one view causes a menu to slide..